# How to display my Navigation bar contents without interruption?

Tags: java, android, menu, navigation-drawer

I built a customizable navigation drawer from scratch(didn't make use of the default drawer provided by Android Studio). In my weather app's navigation bar menu https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIjdx.jpg, whenever I select an option on the menu(say settings), it displays the contents of the option along with the bottom navigation view and my Activity's Toolbar contents which comprises of the nav hamburger icon, the edittext and the search button(the activity hosting my 3 fragments) which spoils the app and makes it look very ugly i.e. https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxj5n.jpg (From that screenshot, the entire content should be empty if implemented well). The case is the same for the other bar menu options. All I want is an empty space to work on, I want the app to only display the navigation bar contents without the rest. Example; https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jtga.png Please how should I do this?

The view of the Navigation Menu is controlled by this code(on line 185):

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings_id:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,
                        new Settings()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.ads_upgrade_id:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,
                        new Upgrade()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.privacy_policy_id:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,
                        new Privacy_Policy()).commit();
                break;
        }
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        return true;
    }
```

"fragment" there represents that I'm currently using my fragment's container view on my activity to display the Nav menu contents which I know is wrong for sure, so what should I use in replace? I lack strong experience as it's my first time building an app and I've tirelessly spent 3 hours on my own trying to figure out the issue which proved abortive.

Here is my Activity code:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    // Last update time, click sound, search button, search panel.
    TextView timeField;
    MediaPlayer player;
    ImageView Search;
    EditText textfield;
    // For scheduling background image change(using constraint layout, start counting from dubai, down to statue of liberty.
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
    public static int count = 0;
    int[] drawable = new int[]{R.drawable.dubai, R.drawable.norway, R.drawable.eiffel_tower, R.drawable.hong_kong, R.drawable.statue_of_liberty,
            R.drawable.beijing, R.drawable.chicago, R.drawable.colombia, R.drawable.vienna,R.drawable.tokyo};
    Timer _t;

    private WeatherDataViewModel viewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        // use home activity layout.

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Allow activity to make use of the toolbar

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(WeatherDataViewModel.class);

        // Trigger action to open & close navigation drawer
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar
                , R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        timeField = findViewById(R.id.textView9);
        Search = findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        textfield = findViewById(R.id.textfield);
        //  find the id's of specific variables.

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        // host 3 fragments along with bottom navigation.
        final NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
        assert navHostFragment != null;
        final NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);

        // Make hourly & daily tab unusable
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {

            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
            return false;
        });

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener((controller, destination, arguments) -> navController.popBackStack(destination.getId(), false));

        // For scheduling background image change
        constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dubai);
        _t = new Timer();
        _t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // run on ui thread
                runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    if (count < drawable.length) {

                        constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(drawable[count]);
                        count = (count + 1) % drawable.length;
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 5000, 5000);

        Search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // make click sound when search button is clicked.
                player = MediaPlayer.create(HomeActivity.this, R.raw.click);
                player.start();

                getWeatherData(textfield.getText().toString().trim());
                // make use of some fragment's data

                Fragment currentFragment = navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);
                if (currentFragment instanceof FirstFragment) {
                    FirstFragment firstFragment = (FirstFragment) currentFragment;
                    firstFragment.getWeatherData(textfield.getText().toString().trim());
                } else if (currentFragment instanceof SecondFragment) {
                    SecondFragment secondFragment = (SecondFragment) currentFragment;
                    secondFragment.getWeatherData(textfield.getText().toString().trim());
                } else if (currentFragment instanceof ThirdFragment) {
                    ThirdFragment thirdFragment = (ThirdFragment) currentFragment;
                    thirdFragment.getWeatherData(textfield.getText().toString().trim());
                }
            }

            private void getWeatherData(String name) {

                ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

                Call<Example> call = apiInterface.getWeatherData(name);

                call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Example> call, @NonNull Response<Example> response) {

                        try {
                            assert response.body() != null;
                            timeField.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            timeField.setText("First Updated:" + " " + response.body().getDt());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            timeField.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            timeField.setText("First Updated: Unknown");
                            Log.e("TAG", "No City found");
                            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "No City found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<Example> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }

                });
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings_id:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,
                        new Settings()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.ads_upgrade_id:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,
                        new Upgrade()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.privacy_policy_id:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,
                        new Privacy_Policy()).commit();
                break;
        }
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
            // Open/close drawer animation
        }
    }
}
```

In case you require any other code to look into the issue, please let me know. I'm just trying to avoid posting too much

**EDIT**:

My old bottomtabs nav graph:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_nav"
    app:startDestination="@id/firstFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
        android:name="com.viz.lightweatherforecast.FirstFragment"
        android:label="fragment_first"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_first" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
        android:name="com.viz.lightpreciseweatherforecast.SecondFragment"
        android:label="fragment_second"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/thirdFragment"
        android:name="com.viz.lightpreciseweatherforecast.ThirdFragment"
        android:label="fragment_third"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_third" />
</navigation>
```

My new nav bar graph:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bar_nav"
    app:startDestination="@id/firstFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
        android:name="com.viz.lightweatherforecast.FirstFragment"
        android:label="fragment_first"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_first" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settings_id"
        android:name="com.viz.lightweatherforecast.Settings"
        android:label="@string/settings"
        tools:layout="@layout/settings" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/ads_upgrade_id"
        android:name="com.viz.lightweatherforecast.Upgrade"
        android:label="@string/upgrade_to_remove_ads"
        tools:layout="@layout/upgrade" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/privacy_policy_id"
        android:name="com.viz.lightweatherforecast.Privacy_Policy"
        android:label="@string/privacy_policy"
        tools:layout="@layout/privacy_policy"/>

</navigation>
```

Comment: You could just toggle the visibility of the bottom bar when you get into a fragment you don't want to show it, unless I'm misunderstanding the requirement?

Comment: @jakelee even if I toggle the visibility of the bottom bar, my activity's contents are still showing. I need to hide the activity's content too

Comment: I just want it to be viewed on a fresh space

Comment: You are using naviagation architecture components, so the navController is the one that should control fragment transactions in the navHostFragment; but in the navDrawer you are do the transaction through `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()` which should be done through the navController instead

Comment: @zain Okay, I can see. I knew the way I set it up was totally wrong because I fully built it following a youtube tutorial which was a basic sample of a different kind of app https://youtu.be/fGcMLu1GJEc but regardless, I'm open to your further suggestions. Thanks for showing up

Comment: @zain got a clue yet?

Comment: It's a bit tricky , but almost got what you want check [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ve6HSyb-g1ctnBWW0jNb8Pa-oHGEvaIr/view) out

Comment: @zain I'm really sorry for showing up late, tried to use my pc since 4 hours ago
but my mouse started acting up so had to spend over 2hrs30mins before I could
get it right. So I've looked over the sample/preview you shared and I must 
admit that it is a good one.

Comment: The settings type is exactly how I want it, except
that those 3 left horizontal small buttons there isn't needed, then I noticed 
that the slideshow type doesn't have its top back button and can only be
navigated from down, I'd have preferred the same to settings but if you have no
other way on it, I'll have to use it only that users may not find it easy.
It also has the 3 left horizontal small buttons too which isn't needed.
But thanks a lot for your help, I'm ready to work on it whenever you send the 
answer.

Comment: I also saw your answer to my previous question https://stackoverflow.com/a/70585466/16020235
thanks a lot, I would accept it when we're done with this question because they
work together as there is no way I can implement the back button without 
fixing this current issue.

Comment: @RichardWilson I'll customize it to yours. it was for testing, Do all drawer items `ads_upgrade_id`, `privacy_policy_id` have the same back button behaviour?

Comment: @zain Okay, is see. All the drawer items currently look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxj5n.jpg so all I need is to implement them to be exactly like the settings sample you sent and yes they currently exit the app when clicking back

Comment: @RichardWilson Can you share your navigation graphs; I think you have a single graph right?

Comment: @zain I've shared my nav graph, yeah I currently have a single nav graph. The firstFragment represents the today, 2nd - hourly and 3rd - daily. Are you saying I should change this graph to the one you're currently suggesting?

Comment: @zain you know the nav graph I'm using is for my other weather tabs but the one you're suggesting is for the navbar menu, should I replace yours with mine or just create a new one for your suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using navigation architecture components, so the `navController` is the one that should control fragment transactions, you are doing that right with `BottomNavigationView`.

But within the `navDrawer` you are doing the transaction through the `supportFragmentManager` which should be done through the `navController` instead as both handle the navigation differently.

> whenever I select an option on the menu(say settings), it displays the contents of the option along with the bottom navigation view

That is because the BottomNavView is a part of the activity, and you need to move it to a fragment; this requires to change the navigation design of your app; to do that change your app navigation like the below:

Main navigation:

```
<navigation
 ..... >

    <fragment
        android:name="......HomeFragment"/>

    <fragment
        android:name="......SettingFragment"/>

    <fragment
        android:name="......AdsUpgradeFragment"/>
        
    <fragment
        android:name="......PrivacyPolicyFragment"/>        
        
        
</navigation>
```

The `HomeFragment` is the fragment that should hold the `BottomNaviagtionView` instead of the activity; and when you navigate to the SettingFragment, the navConroller will replace the entire fragment in the navHostFragment, and therefore the `BottomNaviagtionView` won't be shown.

> my Activity's Toolbar contents which comprises of the nav hamburger
> icon, the edittext and the search button(the activity hosting my 3
> fragments) which spoils the app and makes it look very ugly

Unlike the `BottomNaviagtionView`, you can't do that with your toolBar that is used as the supportActionBar, because setting `supportActionBar` more than once in order to change its look; will duplicates it; so you have to accept a single toolbar; but instead you can hide/show the layout that holds the search button & the EditText whenever the destination changes:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener((controller, destination, arguments) -> {
    LinearLayout searchBar = findViewById(R.id.searchbar); // change searchbar according to the layout id that holds the search button and the EditText
    if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_home) {
        searchBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {
        searchBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

});
```

> and yes they currently exit the app when clicking back

To exit the app whenever, the bottom back button is pressed in any fragment use `OnBackPressedDispatcher()` within `onCreateView()` of those fragment (in your case SettingFragment, PrivacyPolicyFragment, & AdsUpgradeFragment):

And make sure that `appBarConfiguration` doesn't reference those fragments so, that the UP button can be shown instead of the burger.

```
requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        @Override
        public void handleOnBackPressed() {
            // Exit the app when back is pressed
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                requireActivity().finishAndRemoveTask();
            else requireActivity().finish();
        }
    });
```

Also, make sure that your setup the `DrawerLayout` & its `navView` in the `navController` with:

```
NavigationView navView = findViewById(....);

appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
        R.id.nav_home) // remove up button from all these fragments >> Keep the up/back button in R.id.settings_id, R.id.settings_id, ads_upgrade_id, privacy_policy_id
        .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
        .build();

NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
```

And to make the Home fragment hidden by default in the navDrawer:

```
navView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_home).setVisible(false); // adjust R.id.nav_home to yours
```

### UPDATE

> I currently have a single nav graph. The firstFragment represents the
> today, 2nd - hourly and 3rd
> I'm using is for my other weather tabs but the one you're suggesting
> is for the navbar menu, should I replace yours with mine or just
> create a new one for your suggestion?

You should use two navGraphs, the first is for the main navigation which I'd suggested; and the second is for the `BottomNavigationView` navigation which you already use; that is because we transferred the `BottomNavigationView` from the activity layout to the main/home fragment layout; and [it' recommended the `BottomNavigationView` should have a separate navGraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58900349/how-to-handle-nested-bottomnavigationview-with-android-navigation-component);

So, you now need two `FragmentContainerView`; the first is in the activity layout which reference the navGraph provided in this answer, and the second is in the home fragment layout that references your original navGraph of the `BottomNavigationView`.

Sample:

[image]

Comment: The bottomNavigationViews still displays on the activity even after using the first
code, so it still displays on the nav drawer tabs and it gives this error: The navigation graph is not referenced from any layout files(expected to find
it in at least one layout file with a navhostfragment with the app:navgraph=
"@navigation/bar_nav" attribute. 2. I Wrote the 2nd code in my homeactivtity, yet I still see both the search panel,
edittext and the hamburger btn in my nav menu tabs though it runs without error.

Comment: 3. When i used the 3rd code for onbackpressed, I got the following error in all:
Unreachable statement(the entire code was on red). 4. The fourth gave this errors: Cannot resolve symbol appBarConfiguration
bar_nav.

Only the 5th code worked without issue, every other code had issues

Comment: Finally, the new navgraph I created as you suggestion gave the following error:
The navigation graph is not referenced from any layout files(expected to find
it in at least one layout file with a navhostfragment with the app:navgraph=
"@navigation/bar_nav" attribute.

I've included the code of the new bar_nav navgraph I just created in my question.

Comment: Wow, I wish I could leave the bottom nav in the activity but just toggle it not to reflect in those fragments because at this point, I've gotten really confused, everything I'm doing is not working. I'll need like a day to get things together but thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @RichardWilson Great, the `BottomNavigationView` should have a separate navigation graph, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58900349/how-to-handle-nested-bottomnavigationview-with-android-navigation-component) out. Feel free if you want to send you my sample project; but first give it a try so that you can learn it

Comment: Good day, I think you're in the best position to handle it, I have tried all your
suggestions severally to no avail and I'm sure that the only way I can handle
it again is if I take several months on it so I'm pleading with you if I can
share the necessary docs for you to handle it https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1TQXACcf7OXSXbrywzT_cVKSYtXA1RfSe?usp=sharing
I made most of the code default so you can see how it was before and won't be confused when making the corrections

Comment: The bottomNaviagtionView is currently in the activity's layout, you can copy that exact one to the first fragment's and remove it from the activity, I just left it there to avoid confusion

Comment: @RichardWilson Plz [check these](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vbIT39R9KlzxcQeDUBzN5lEX6FRYBfCH/view?usp=sharing) changes summarized in changes.txt

Comment: First, this code in the activity https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/ekihulocom.properties returns the error I wrote below on the code. Secondly, I removed that code to test the app to see how it runs, I noticed that immediately after my splash screen has finished playing its animation, it chills for a short while then displays a blank black screen, so the entire
screen shows black immediately after the splash screen i.e. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BthYg.png and stays like that, nothing else loads after. I've used up the entire code you've sent and got no compilation errors, thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240849/discussion-between-richard-wilson-and-zain).

Comment: Thanks a lot man, just emailed it now

Comment: If possible, please include the changes made

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood your problem very well (if I am not wrong). Thing is that what behavior you are getting right now is the normal scenario. You are using the same host activity to host both `Navigation Drawer` and `Bottom Navigation` fragments thus when you tried to navigate to another fragment from the same host the presence of the host's direct child view Bottom `NavBar` is showing. I think you can solve this problem in a few different but **pretty simple logical ways**.

1. *(Not recommended)* Using a different **Activity** for the `Settings` page. Just like `startActivity(this, <some intent>)`. But in this way, you will end up creating lots of individual activities.
2. **(Recommended)** Using a **common Navigation Host** activity for navigating to independent pages/fragments. Like: Settings, Contact Us, etc. You can add different fragments into the `common_nav_graph` and set some actions with or without arguments for navigation. Just add the `common_nav_graph` as a nested graph inside your current one and set a simple argumented action. The arguments will help you to navigate desired pages/fragments without showing the `bottom navigation bar`.
3. Simply hide Bottom navigation when navigating to some fragments from your drawer.